# Why the function seems to import once?

Tags: python, python-import

I have three files `file_a.py`, `file_b.py` and `func.py`:

In `func.py`, I have:

```
import datetime

def a_simple_function():
    print("hello from simple function")
    return datetime.datetime.now()

global_variable = a_simple_function()
```

In `file_b.py`, I have:

```
from func import global_variable  # second time import

def func_in_b():
    print("print from file b:", global_variable)
```

In `file_a.py`, I have:

```
from func import global_variable  # first time import 
from file_b import func_in_b

print("print from file a:", global_variable)
func_in_b()
```

When run from `file_a`, I see the following output:

```
hello from simple function
print from file a: 2019-06-17 14:14:42.293202
print from file b: 2019-06-17 14:14:42.293202
```

Why does `hello from simple function` appear once instead of twice? I think I've imported it twice in different files.

Basically I am trying to set a `global_variable` used both in `file_a.py` and `file_b.py`, the `global_variable` is generated by a function in file `func.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how importing works, as documented: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules. Specifically:

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. They are executed only the *first* time the module name is encountered in an import statement.

Basically, the `import` statement first checks if `sys.modules` contains your module already. If it does, the existing reference is returned, as in your second case. If not, an empty module object is created, added to `sys.modules`, and only then populated by running the .py file. The reason for doing it this way is to avoid loops from circular imports: a module won't be reloaded in such a loop, even if it's object is still empty.

The references to `global_variable` in all three files point to the exact same object. You can check in `file_a` by adding the following to the existing code:

```
import func
import file_b
import sys

print(func.global_variable is file_b.global_variable is global_variable is sys.modules['func'].global_variable)
```

One caveat to keep in mind is that running a module as a script will place it in `sys.modules` under the name `__main__`. Any code that tries to import it under its usual name will load a different module object, sometimes leading to unexpected consequences.

Comment: can you explain the  ' caveat' by example?

Answer (score 3):

Python caches imports in `sys.modules`. So even if you import the same module multiple times, it will use the cached versions instead of repeatedly importing.

Read about the [module cache](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you imported global_variable in file `file_a.py`, the function `a_simple_function()` is defined in memory and saved in python cache.
The next time you import the global_variable in file `file_b.py`, the function `a_simple_function()` is already in cache so it will not be defined again, instead you will take the value of `global_variable` from there.

Comment: What cache are you referring to?

Comment: it is python cache

Comment: Is there a documentation link for that?

Comment: it is mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)

Comment: It's the "module cache", not the "python cache". Precise terminology is important.